# Apache Camel + CXF endpoint authenticatiion

Tags: java, cxf, apache-camel

i need to secure simple rest service in Camel, like these

```
<cxf:rsServer id="usrServer" address="${host}"
                  serviceClass="..."
                  loggingFeatureEnabled="true" loggingSizeLimit="20"/>
```

but i have no idea how to enable authentication on this endpoint, for examle Digest authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You have essentially two ways of achieving this:

1. Configure your apache-camel runtime container to handle the authentication i.e. if you are deploying to Tomcat then configure Tomcat to handle the Digest authentication. ServiceMix and Karaf will use the OSGI PAX web server which will need to be configured.
2. To secure your CXF REST service please review the CXF documentation around [REST service security](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/secure-jax-rs-services.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 1) Yes, i have Camel in Karaf, and setting PAX server configuration probably solve the problem, but i plan to have multiple REST\SOAP endpoints in my OSGi bundles. And would be better if they suppoort different credentials. 2) Of course i saw Apache CXF documentation, but i'm pretty new in this programmig stack. Just have no idea how to bind authentication handler to camel-cxf endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

There's somes ways to secure a rest service and in my opinion it doesn't depends on Camel.

For example, you want to allow access to the service event if the client is not logged. So you have to check his information in the body of you service.
That's one way.

One other way, is to use authentication (by login/pwd, token, etc...). That force to have 1 request to obtain your credentials, and 1 request to the service you want.

So, it you want to use Digest authentication, why not. But you have to configure it in your web server, not on the rest service configuration.

Here are a link for apache : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/fr/mod/mod_auth_digest.html
and a like for tomcat http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html

I'm not very used to security, so i don't know if it's help.
cheers

Comment: The apache documentation is not applicable here as Camel wont be able to deploy to Apache web server at all from my experience. However the concept that "CORE" Camel is not responsible for the security is correct. The apache CXF component is.

Comment: You're right, i talked about apache if it was used as a front server. I should have specify that. thanks for answering